# What is the "maximum attempts to connect to shell" in PyDev's code completion?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

What is the "maximum attempts to connect to shell" in PyDev's code completion?

[image]

I use Eclipse 4.5 with PyDev 4.3.0.201508182223 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev launches an instance of Python to help generate code completion suggestions. The preference controls how long PyDev waits for a connection back from the child Python process before giving up.

PyDev (in Java) launches Python. On the Java side a socket server is created and the child Python process has a command line argument to indicate the port to connect back to. PyDev then waits for the Python process to connect to the server. The preference controls how long that socket has to make a connection. Typically it will be much less than 1 second.

If you examine the eclipse process tree, you will see a child process of eclipse (or java, depending on how your JVM is set up) that looks a little like this if things are working OK. It is this process that is being communicated with.

```
<path to>\python.exe -u <path to>\org.python.pydev_<version>\pysrc\pycompletionserver.py <port number>
```

If you want to look under the hood, on [Line 303 of AbstractShell.java](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/pydev_4_3_0/plugins/org.python.pydev/src_completions/org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/shell/AbstractShell.java#L303) the variable `maxAttempts` gets set to the preference value. If you follow that logic you will see if PyDev fails to establish communications over a socket as intended it will destroy the launched Python process.